# Entity Framework SQLite intermediary tables not generated

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite, mvvm

I would like to generate a model from an existing database. My database is relational and has many-to-many relation with intermediary tables containing two foreign keys.

For example: `Point`, `Person`, and `PointPerson` with FK to `Point` and FK to `Person`.

When I use "Generate Model from Database" in VS 2015, it just creates entities of all the tables (including `PointPerson`), without relations, and in consequence, there are no collections in the `Point` and `Person` classes to each other.

Can I generate it properly (relation in model, `PointPerson` in database) somehow, or do I have to do it in code-first?

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: @LeiYang System.Data.SQLite by SQLite dev team 1.0.105